# Geoserver SLD: link to symbol in database instead of file

Tags: geoserver, symbology, sld, database

I have a PostgreSQL table with fields:

- 'id' with identificators of objects types (e.g. shops, cinemas etc),
- 'graphic' with SVG codes of correcponding map symbols.

I want to create sld style with links to graphic in this table, instead any files.

EXAMPLE

Classic style:

```
<PointSybmolizer>
    ...
    <Graphic>
        <ExternalGraphic>
            <OnlineResource xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="sign.svg"/>
            <Format>image/svg+xml</Format>
        </ExternalGraphic>
    </Graphic>
</PointSymbolizer>
```

And style I want:

```
<PointSybmolizer>
    ...
    <Graphic>
        <!-- Link to database record with same sign.svg -->
    </Graphic>
<PointSymbolizer>
```

Are there methods to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

This can be done using something like:

`<ExternalGraphic>
   <OnlineResource xlink:type="simple"
                   xlink:href="http://mysite.com/images/${graphic}.svg"/>
   <Format>image/svg+xml</Format>
</ExternalGraphic>`

You can check this usage on the [Geoserver documentation](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/sld/extensions/pointsymbols.html#external-graphics).

Your `graphic` field can contain the name of the symbol, the filename, a path or a complete URL.

Answer (score 1):

What you suggest cannot be done without changing GeoServer own code, see here in case you're interested in making changes:
https://github.com/geoserver/geoserver/blob/master/src/main/src/main/java/org/geoserver/config/GeoServerDataDirectory.java#L1199